# Add Upload File button to a custom object

Tags: custom-button, files, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I am working on an assignment where I built a custom object on top of files (ContentVersion, ContentDocumentLink, ContentDocument). Since the customizability of files is limited in Salesforce, we are planning to use the custom object to approve/reject a file, use them in reports etc. Our stakeholders are asking that we should remove the Files related list on the Contact, but allow users to upload the files from the custom object related list. Is it possible to add a custom "Upload File" button on the custom object related list under Contact?

Comment: yep - see https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000lFzwQAE

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry if my question was not clear. I know how to create a list view button on the child object and to add the same to the parent object. The question is specifically about the Salesforce Files, which is a special kind of object. It does not support custom buttons. More over, when I click the "Upload File" custom button, I want the file open dialog to be shown up so that the users the users can upload their files. The uploaded file should create all the necessary records in the objects related to files (ContentVersion, ContentDocumentLink, ContentDocument) etc.

Comment: Hmm.  One option I’ve done is to create my own custom related list component with whatever custom buttons you need.  More work, for sure.